# Resampling with Python console (QGIS): number of parameters

Tags: qgis, python, parameters, resampling

I am trying to resample two raster layers with Python console in QGIS with this code:

```
outputs_0=Processing.runAlgorithm("saga:resampling", 'G:/DOCTORAT/2014/Incendis/Dades/LST/LST_TERRA/Tiff/2012/UTM30N/2012153_day.tif', True, 0, 0, 0, "-81084.51, 1138915.49, 3972094.6, 4861094.6", 1000.0, 'G:/DOCTORAT/2014/Incendis/Dades/LST/LST_TERRA/Tiff/2012/FINALS/2012153_day_FINAL.tif')
```

I got this:

> Error: Wrong number of parameters

However, it seems to contain all needed parameters:

```
INPUT <ParameterRaster>
KEEP_TYPE <ParameterBoolean>
TARGET <ParameterSelection>
SCALE_UP_METHOD <ParameterSelection>
SCALE_DOWN_METHOD <ParameterSelection>
OUTPUT_EXTENT <ParameterExtent>
USER_SIZE <ParameterNumber>
USER_GRID <OutputRaster>
```

Someone could please help me?

Comment: Does it work fine if you run it via the GUI (Processing Toolbox)?

Comment: Yes, it works correctly this way :-)

Answer (score 1):

Another method is to use Model Builder via the Processing Toolbox:

- Create a model to run the **SAGA:Resampling** algorithm with all the required parameters
- Save the model (make sure to add a *model name* and *group name* in the text boxes)
- Exit the Model Builder and you should see your saved model in the list under the group name you provided (Processing Toolbox > Models > (*group name)*
- Right-click on the model and select to **Save as Python script**

Now you can see what the python script should be and compare it with what you had to see where you went wrong.